# How far apart should PCB traces be for mains isolation?

Tags: pcb, power, high-voltage

As a hobby project I'm building a power line monitor to detect when a load is switched on and turns on some additional loads.  I have <strike>120 V</strike> 220 V running through my board and was curious what the standard board spacing is for high voltages.

I'm sure there's some specs by UL or other agencies for this, but I'm cheap.

#### Edit:

Correction, the voltage I'm working with is 220 V, powers a cabinet saw.  In any case, is there a general formula, possibly even for higher voltages (e.g. flyback for fluorescent lights)

Comment: I don't know a rule off the top of my head, if you decide to look at actual regulations then IEC 60950 is what your after but i don't think you can get that for free.

Comment: It pisses me off that IEC, ISO and the like want money for their standards documentation. They already get membership fees, don't they? And if I had the rights to some standard, I would love to see it spread as much as possible. A job for wikileaks, maybe? :-)

Comment: @steven - You can register for free with the [JEDEC standards body](http://www.jedec.org/); their motto is "Leading developer of standards for the solid-state industry, all being available online, free of charge." Not applicable here, but useful in many other cases like memory and layout design!

Answer (score 9):

Minimum 2.5mm for standard insulation (across mains), 5mm for reinforced ("double") insulation (mains to low-voltage)

Comment: Allowances for board creepage distances will make this larger, too.

Comment: Wait, Is this for insulation *thickness*? Cause it's **insane** for adjacent traces on a PCB (even with soldermask).

Comment: Sounds about right for adjacent tracks and pads. Not insane, required to prevent flashover. Dirt and moisture levels affect the distance required. If you don't use these sort of creepage distance, you are creating a safety hazard. In Europe, that comes under the Low Voltage Directive and associated standards; equivalent in US is UL.

Comment: IIRC IEC needs 5.5mm for double insulation (may even be 6mm). An DIL optocoupler with standard pads doesn't comply.

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at footprint of smallest 400-600V capacitor (which is minimum DC for 220V AC, with peak-to-peak 310V, so overrate is extra 33..100%). 
If its pins are 15..20 mm apart (I have not seen less than this), then with traces it makes about 11..17 mm. gap.

Answer (score 0):

Various standards I have read seem to indicate 1.5-2mm for mains-mains, and 6-8mm for mains-low voltage.

(Note I mean mains = "low voltage", low voltage = "safety extra low voltage in standards terminology)

Comment: References could make this a much better answer.